# What does Continuous x aesthetic -- did you forget aes(group=...) mean?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
Scatterplot<-ggplot(
     diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ],
     aes(carat, price, colour=clarity)
  )+
  geom_point(position="jitter", alpha=0.6)+
  facet_grid(~cut) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 5, 1)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0, colour="black") +  
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
  plot(Scatterplot)
```

I cannot find any clue about this warning. Anyone knows? Please check the picture:

[image: output]

Comment: What is it that you think the continuous x aes will do for you? Since your image doesn't show x it is hard to tell, but how do you want it to be different?

Comment: Search for your message on this page  https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html   it explains the issue specifically.

Comment: Take a look at the docs for `geom_boxplot`. It expects a discrete x value and a continuous y value. You've given continuous for both

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your answers. I have tried JonGrub's solution and problem solved. To assign a group value is really not interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get around it with adding `group = 1`:

```
Scatterplot<-ggplot(
  diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ],
  aes(carat, price, colour=clarity, group = 1)
)+
  geom_point(position="jitter", alpha=0.6)+
  facet_grid(~cut) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 5, 1)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0, colour="black") +  
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
plot(Scatterplot)
```

This removes the error. However, I did not check if your overall approach to this plot makes sense (see comments).

Regarding why `group = 1` is necessary: I would recommend [this chapter in *R for Data Science*](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html#statistical-transformations).

Comment: Thank you, Jon, it is clear now. We treat the "1" as a character for grouping.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me because the `x` column wasn't character (it was numeric).

Simply `mutate` to character i.e.

```
mutate(myvariable = as.character(myvariable))
```